# How to compare json responses?

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

I need to compare json response in beanshell sampler and print if the condition is passed or failed. Can someone please help, how do we compare it ?
I already have a response in json format and one i will be getting another when the test is executed, i ned to compare those two word to word.

```
 I tried using if/else but then its not working properly.


JSONObject JsonResponseinput = new JSONObject();
JsonResponseinput.toString();

print(JsonResponseinput +  " = PASS");
    f.close();

String s=JsonResponseinput.toString();

if (s == JsonResponse)
{
    f = new FileOutputStream("output/path/API_OUTPUT.csv", true);
     p = new PrintStream(f);
     this.interpreter.setOut(p);
    print(s +  " = PASS");
    f.close();
}
Else
{
    print(JsonResponseinput +  " = FAIL")

}
```

Comment: What's `JsonResponse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 4 ways of doing this:

1. Using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) like:

   ```
   final JSONObject obj1 = /*json*/;
   final JSONObject obj2 = /*json*/;
   final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   final JsonNode tree1 = mapper.readTree(obj1.toString());
   final JsonNode tree2 = mapper.readTree(obj2.toString());
   if (tree1.equals(tree2)) {
        log.info('PASS');
   }
   else {
        log.info('FAIL')
   }
   ```
2. Using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) like:

   ```
   JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
   JsonElement o1 = parser.parse("{a : {a : 2}, b : 2}");
   JsonElement o2 = parser.parse("{b : 2, a : {a : 2}}");
   assertEquals(o1, o2);
   ```
3. Using [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) like:

   ```
   def json1 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText("json1")
   def json2 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText("json2")

   if (json1 == json2) {
       log.info('PASS')
   } else {
       log.info('FAIL')
   }
   ```
4. Using [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) like

   ```
   try {
       org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals("json1", "json2", false)
       println('PASS')
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       println('FAIL')
   }
   ```

More information: [The Easiest Way To Compare REST API Responses Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-easiest-way-to-compare-rest-api-responses-using-jmeter/)

P.S. Forget about Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting

Answer (score 1):

You can compare 2 JSON Response using following ways:

1. Extract both the JSON Responses using JSON Extractor [extract full Response]
2. Use JSR223 Sampler to process the code in Script area

   ```
   String response1 = vars.get("jsonOutput1");
   String response2 = vars.get("jsonOutput2");

   if (response1.equals(response2)) {
   log.info("Responses are equal");
   }
   else {
       log.info("Responses are not equal");
   }
   ```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use a tool called DeltaJSON from DeltaXML for JSON comparison there is a neat GUI and REST interface. You could use the REST API and parse the response.